# Polymer - Access element in dom-if template

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

```
<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template id="methodScope">
    <paper-dialog id="modal1">
      <paper-swatch-picker></paper-swatch-picker>
      <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Fertig</paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
    <paper-toast id="copiedColor" text="Farbe in die Zwischenablage kopiert!"></paper-toast>
  </template>

  <template id="create" is="dom-if" if="{{mapChosen}}" restamp="true">
    <iron-ajax auto url$="{{mapJson}}" handle-as="json" last-response="{{mapData}}"></iron-ajax>

    <paper-button id="button1">Data</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      attached: function(event) {
        dialog = this.$.modal1;
        colorPick = this.$.colorpicker;
        var self = this;
        this.$.colorpicker.addEventListener('color-picker-selected',function() {
          self._alertColor()
          self.selectedColor = colorPick.color;
          self.copyToClipboard(colorPick.color);
          dialog.close();
          console.log("fired");
        })
      }
      var button = this.$.button1;
    });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Accessing elements outside of the `dom-if` template works perfectly, but no matter what I do, I cannot access them inside of it.
I already tried using `this.async` and `this.$$` - all returning undefined.
How would I be able to access the button in the template with the `dom-if` and id "create"?

I've cut some of the code, so if you don't see some functions or other things, that's because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listening on `dom-change` event. Below is an example for `dom-repeat` but same should work with `dom-if` also

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="repeat-completion">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item" on-dom-change="_domComplete">
      <div id$="num{{index}}">{{item}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'repeat-completion',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      }
    },
    _domComplete: function(e) {
      if (e.returnValue)
        console.log(this.$$("#num1"));
    }
  })
</script>


<repeat-completion></repeat-completion>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
That solves my accessing problem, but how would I add an eventListener for the button?

Comment: you want to add a listener on button's tap action?

Comment: yes, as I couldn't before, because I couldn't even access it

Comment: For that you don't need to access the button. just add `on-tap="name_of_polymer_function"` in the markup of button

Comment: Ok, but the problem is, I need to access another element, also in that template using that function and if I declare the function in the normal Polymer part, I'll just get undefined again..

Comment: In the function that you create for `on-tap` you can access that element using `this.$$`. As you `dom-if` has for sure rendered by then (else button would not have been visible) you should be able to access the element

Comment: The function gets called but "console.log(this.$$.HOT);" (HOT is the id of the element) returns undefined :(

Comment: Usage is similar to `querySelector`. It'll be `this.$$('#HOT')`